# How to find smallest Transition between two angles

Tags: java, math

I have a Java program in which one object needs to rotate to another object. For this I calculate the angles of the two Vectors and then the difference between them. Now I need to find out which will be the smallest transition between them. For example if the angle of the first vector -179° and the angle to the second vector is 179° the smallest rotation angle would be 2° and the rotation don't needs to be a whole round rotation : -179° -2° = - 181° = 179.
I hope the explanation is ok.
So how can I easy calculate this in Java?
I have a little bloackade in my head and can't figure this out.

Edit: the angles are in radians

```
angle_Knight = atan2(knightNode.getLocalTranslation().y,knightNode.getLocalTranslation().x));
angle_follow = atan2(followKnight.getLocalTranslation().y,followKnight.getLocalTranslation().x));
angle = angle_follow - angle_Knight;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Just add or subtract a full turn (360 degrees or 2pi radians) when the angle resulting angle is outside the (-pi, pi) range.

```
angle = angle_follow - angle_Knight;
if (angle < -Math.PI) {
    angle = angle + 2*Math.PI;
} else if (angle > Math.PI) {
    angle = angle - 2*Math.PI;
}
```

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks for your fast reply!